# Gitlab cross-reference project

Tags: gitlab, markdown

I am trying to find the best way to document my project in Gitlab. And I found two different alternatives:

- Markdown in the actual repository (`my-repo.git`)
- Wiki using markdown (`my-repo/wiki.git`)

Note that the suffix `.git` indicates that these are two different git repositories.

I like the approach to simply modify the Wiki using markdown from the webpage (for everyones simplicity), but I am missing how to link between them or any other project in Gitlab.

In the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#special-gitlab-references) is provided some information to link (issues, commits, etc...) to other projects but not link files like the `README.md` and other documentation.

Is there such functionality?

Answer (score 4):

I also don't know if I am 100% getting your question, but Gitlab does support [special syntax for referencing other projects/commits/etc.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#gitlab-specific-references).

You can reference other project like so,

```
namespace/project>
```

It doesn't support referencing files in other projects (as far as I can tell), but you can reference files in the same project:

```
[README](doc/README.md)
```

And to specify a line number:

```
[README](doc/README.md#L13)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I get your point to 100%.

**Linking** to other "files" is like links to any URL / URI in markdown. Use the ["well-known"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#wiki-specific-markdown) syntax `[LinkName](LinkTarget)`.

A Link inside the same project

```markdown
[Link to file, relative path](./README.md)
```

This should work in WIKIs and Project Markdown-files.

```markdown
[Link to a file from other project](https://gitlab.com/{{USER or COMPANY}}/{{PROJECT}}/-/blob/master/{{FOLDER}}/README.md)
```

You can also use the reference syntax for links `[LinkName][LinkReference]` and then later in your file `[LinkReference]: https://gitlab.com/foobar/123` when you want to reuse your links or collect them at the end of your file.

Comment: `./readme.md` works to link files in the same folder as the current md file is in.